# SQL selecting results from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hello I want to display results from unrelated tables where a text string exists in a column which is common to all tables in the database. 
I can get the desired result with this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
WHERE Title LIKE '%Text%' 

UNION 

SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
WHERE Title LIKE '%Text%'`
```

However my question is is there a more efficient way to go about this as I need to search dozens of tbls. Thanks for any help you can give!

ps the system I am using supports most dialects but would prefer to keep it simple with SQL Server as that is what I am used to.

Comment: Consider using a full text index in the tables.

Comment: So the solution isn't in a different type of query?

Answer (score 0):

There is a SP script you can find online called SearchAllTables (http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm).

When you call it pass in the string, it will return the tables and columns as well as the full string.

You can modify it to work with other datatypes quite easily. It's a fantastic resource for tasks exactly like yours.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - not applicable here as I am using a system that you can only query but thanks as I can use it in future ;)

Comment: That's unfortunate, Thomas. You could pull the queries out of the SP and hard code the value you are looking for. That way you are just running a series of select statements.